# How can I access the doClick() method of a Java Swing JCheckBox from a different package?

Tags: java, swing

I have inherited, and am working on a Java Swing application. This application has a particular `JCheckBox` I need to click from a different package which contains some back-end code.

There is, of course, the `doClick()` method, but there is an issue. This code was created using NetBeans and all the JComponents are automatically created as non-static and package-private. This means I cannot access this checkbox even with a public getters and setters, as I need to make them static methods.

I used Vim to make the `JCheckBox` static so I can use `public static` getters and setters, but NetBeans always finds a way to revert this external change back to non-static.

Rewriting that code is not an option as it would be a non-trivial process. Am I overlooking the obvious or should I keep trying to manhandle that field back to `static`?

Thanks

Comment: You should instead call it from the current class and inside that method call your function in the other package...

Comment: *"I cannot access this checkbox even with a public getters and setters"* - Well, that's just plainly incorrect, *"as I need to make them static methods."* - No, you just need to manage the instances better. *"Am I overlooking the obvious or should I keep trying to manhandle that field back to static?"* - `static` is not your friend and I would avoid trying to use in this way, as it's unlikely to produce the results you're after

Comment: @MadProgrammer The class is the way it is because NetBeans generated it that way. Unless I make some manual changes, how else can I "manage" it better?

Comment: You manage the instances of the class rather then trying to change the access to its state - static is not your friend

Comment: @MadProgrammer I like static. It keeps me from having to instantiate an entire class just for one method ... especially in classes that I don't have much control over.

Comment: @Brian `static`, in this context, is a hack to avoid proper management of the objects state. `static` makes it difficult to reason about the state of the component and removes the possibility of having multiples instances of the object available during runtime, something which will happen a lot in GUIs. `static` is not your friend